# Determine whether the given function $F(x,y) = x/y$ is as binary operation on the given set $A$

Tags: functions, binary-operations

The given function is $F(x,y) = x/y$ for all $x$ and $y$ in the set $A$.

where $A = \{a+b \sqrt[]{2} : a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$
and $a$ and $b$ cant be both $0.$

So what I need is to prove $F(x,y) \in A$ for every $x,y \in A$

Here is what I tried:

Let $x = \frac{p}{q} +\frac{m}{n} \sqrt[]2$ and $y =\frac{u}{v} +\frac{k}{j} \sqrt[]2$

Then $$F(x,y) = \frac{\frac{p}{q} +\frac{m}{n} \sqrt[]2}{\frac{u}{v} +\frac{k}{j} \sqrt[]2}$$
$$F(x,y) = \frac{\frac{pn+mq \sqrt[]{2}}{qn}}{\frac{uk+kv \sqrt[]{2}}{vj}}$$
$$F(x,y) = \frac{pn+mq \sqrt[]{2}}{qn}.\frac{vj}{uk+kv \sqrt[]{2}}$$
$$F(x,y) = \frac{vjpn+vjmq \sqrt[]{2}}{qnuj+qnkv \sqrt[]{2}}$$

I got stuck here, It dont seems that the result of this function will always produce number in the format of the elements from $A$, how can I show this if it is the case?

Comment: Now remove the irrationality from the denominator (multiply both by $.... - ....\sqrt{2}$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $y=0=0+0\sqrt{2}\in A$, the function $F$ is not well defined, but I assume you just missed that.

In general, if you have a fraction $\frac{a+b\sqrt{2}}{c+d\sqrt{2}}$ you can multiply above and below y $c-d\sqrt{2}$, which gives you

$$\frac{(ac-2bd)+(-ad+bc)\sqrt{2}}{c^2+2d^2}$$

which is clearly in $A$.

Comment: I missed the part from the definition of the set $A$ which states $a$ and $b$ cant be both 0,

I will add it, thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome.